# If $\lfloor{x^2-x}\rfloor= \lfloor{x^2-11x}\rfloor=1380$ the find $A=\lfloor{x^2-6x}\rfloor-380$

Tags: calculus, functions

We know that

$$\lfloor{x^2-x}\rfloor= \lfloor{x^2-11x}\rfloor=1380$$

Know how to find $$A=\lfloor{x^2-6x}\rfloor-380$$
Actually i dont have any ideas. Do you help me with finding $A$?

Comment: You may use any value of $A$ you like and it would be valid. This is because the problem has a false premise, since $\lfloor x^2-x \rfloor = \lfloor x^2-11x \rfloor$ implies $|10x|<1$, so $\frac{-9}{100}<x^2-x<\frac{11}{100}$ and clealy $1380$ is too far outside of these bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know (if i correctly understand the notations):
$$
\begin{aligned}
1380&\le x^2-x< 1381\ ,\\
1380&\le x^2-11x< 1381\ ,\\
     &\qquad\text{so we add and divide by $2$ getting...}\\
1380&\le x^2-6x< 1381\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The above solves the problem.

It would be nice to also get a value for $x$ matching the double inequalities... (So that the situation is indeed realized.)

But such an $x$ does not exist. So any $A$ / no $A$ works...

Answer (score 2):

Since

$$\lfloor{x^2-x}\rfloor= \lfloor{x^2-11x}\rfloor$$

Everything inbetween will be the same
$$\lfloor{x^2-x}\rfloor= \lfloor{x^2-11x}\rfloor=\lfloor{x^2-6x}\rfloor=1380$$
Thus $$\lfloor{x^2-6x}\rfloor-380=1380-380=1000$$

Answer (score 0):

$\lfloor{x^2-x}\rfloor= \lfloor{x^2-11x}\rfloor=1380\implies x^2-x,\  x^2-11x\in [1380, 1381)\\ x^2-6x=\frac{2x^2-12x}{2}=\frac{x^2-x+x^2-11x}{2}\in [1380, 1381)$